# How to draw multiple sprites in one class

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a space shooter game which has a planets in the background. I've decided to draw some planets in the background and when i move to the right the planets should move to the left. That is for the player to feel the spaceship is moving around the space. However i could have done it for one planet only. When try to apply the other planets in one class it is constantly changing to the other planet.

```
lanetdic = {'planets':[]}
imagestoload = ['Feza/graphs/sprites/saturne.png']
for i in imagestoload:
    img = pg.image.load(i).convert_alpha()
    planetdic['planets'].append(img)
```

this is to load the sprite. and in the below i created a class for the planets.

```
class Planets(pg.sprite.Group):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Group.__init__(self)
        self.frame = 0
        self.image = planetdic['planets'][self.frame]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (500+100*self.frame,HEIGHT/2)
        self.pos = vec(500,HEIGHT/2)
        self.vel = vec(0,0)
        self.acc = vec(0,0)
    def update(self):
        #self.acc = vec(0,0)
        self.frame = (self.frame + 1)%len(planetdic['planets'])
```

Maybe it is not sensible to create a class for a planet but i couldnt have find anotherway if there is please tell me.

if we get to the point again. In the below i made a for loop to load images. and used again the same for loop

```
planetdic = {'planets':[]}
    imagestoload = ['Feza/graphs/sprites/saturne.png','Feza/graphs/sprites/jupiter.png','Feza/graphs/sprites/venus.png','Feza/graphs/sprites/uranus.png','Feza/graphs/sprites/neptune.png']
    for i in imagestoload:
        img = pg.image.load(i).convert_alpha()
        planetdic['planets'].append(img)
```

When i apply multi images it changes one to other in miliseconds how can i prevent this happen. I just want to show every planets in the background and make them move.

Comment: *"How to draw multiple sprites in one class"* - You do not do that. However, you can create multiple [instance objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects)  of a class.

Comment: oh yes now this is sensible thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to draw multiple sprites in one class

You do not do that. However, you can create multiple [instance objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects) of a class.

The image (*Surface*) must be a parameter of the constructor of the class `Planet`. The `Planet` class is a subcalss of [`sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite), not [`sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group):

```py
class Planet(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image):
        pg.sprite.Group.__init__(self)
        self.frame = 0
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (500+100*self.frame,HEIGHT/2)
        self.pos = vec(500,HEIGHT/2)
        self.vel = vec(0,0)
        self.acc = vec(0,0)
```

Create a new instance object of the `Planet` class for each planet:

```py
planets = pg.sprite.Group()
imagestoload = ['Feza/graphs/sprites/saturne.png','Feza/graphs/sprites/jupiter.png','Feza/graphs/sprites/venus.png','Feza/graphs/sprites/uranus.png','Feza/graphs/sprites/neptune.png']
for filepath in imagestoload:
    img = pg.image.load(filepath).convert_alpha()
    planet = Planet(img)
    planets.add(planet)
```